# Skyrim: Golden Claw - Turning in

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I went through the dungeon did the fight got the dragonstone but when i try to return the claw it forces the barter menu. Any idea what might fix it?

Comment: Two questions, (a) is the claw still in your inventory and (b) has he given you the quest yet? (ie is it in your journal)

Comment: Just a thought, but have you tried to navigate the dialogue with keyboard to ensure you are picking the right choice, since those menus sometimes get a bit dodgy?

Answer (score 4):

Try saving your game, and killing the NPC.

Now, reload your save, and you should find the problem has been fixed. This is how I solve problems like this.

Comment: Classical Skyrim NPC fix.